# Is there a way to convert a number to a series of virtual key-codes?

Tags: c++, keycode

For example, would there be a way that I could do the following?

```
//string converted = ConvertToVirtual(int numberToConvert);

string converted = ConvertToVirtual(12);
```

converted would then hold "0x31 0x32".

Ideally, the number passed into the function could be of any number of digits, but for now, I am just wondering if this is possible, and how I could go about it?

Thank you very much in advance (:

Comment: What's this "virtual key-code" you're referring to? In the two thousand pages that make up the technical specifications for the current C++ standard, there's no mention of anything called a "virtual key-code". What is it? If it's just some kind of a list of values, referenced by a single numeric value, just make an array or a map of them, and have this function look it up, and return it. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Convert your int to a string, then convert each character of the string to an int, then convert each of those ints to a string with `0x` slapped on the front.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Wouldn't there be an additional step to go from decimal to hex after converting to int

Comment: @BigRed118 when it's an int it's in binary. No going from decimal to hex to octal or anything. What would converting a decimal int to a hex int even look like?

Comment: @JohnFilleau I just meant he's looking to display 0x31 for 1, not 0x49. If you just slap on the converted ints it'll be base 10 not 16. All I'm saying is just make sure it's in base 16.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <ios>

std::string ConvertToVirtual(int num)
{
    std::string numStr = std::to_string(num);
    std::stringstream output;
    output << std::hex; // this will convert all following data to hex
    for (const char& c : str)
    {
        output << "0x" << (int)c << " "; 
    }
    return output.str(); // extract string from stringstream
}
```